# Fast way to transfer table to a remote server as import/export does

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

I have a stored procedure with statements similar to this:

```
DELETE FROM [LinkedServer].[DB1].[dbo].[Table1]
DELETE FROM [LinkedServer].[DB1].[dbo].[Table2]
DELETE FROM [LinkedServer].[DB1].[dbo].[Table3]

INSERT INTO [LinkedServer].[DB1].[dbo].[Table3] 
    SELECT * FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Table3]
INSERT INTO [LinkedServer].[DB1].[dbo].[Table2] 
    SELECT * FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Table2]
INSERT INTO [LinkedServer].[DB1].[dbo].[Table1] 
    SELECT * FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Table1]
```

Which is extremely slow. But my goal is simple as this.

I cannot use replication, just a method to empty the tables and fill them again.

If I do the same action using import/export functionality from SSMS, it empties the remote tables and fill them up very quickly.

Is there a way to simulate what import/export is doing, using T-SQL commands?

It would not be a problem to disable restrictions while copying data.
Perhaps exists some kind of `BULK INSERT` I could use in this scenario? After search info about this option it seems to be useful to transfer data from SQL to file or from file to SQL, but I don't find examples to transfer from table to table.

Comment: I would perhaps look at running this *on* the linked server and selecting data *from* this server, if that's possible.

Comment: This is also not possible in my case, as the source server is a very old version (SQL2000) and the linked server is SQL2012

Comment: No, there is no such way, at least not with pure T-SQL. Import/export is using client-side code to read the rows and stream them to the server using the bulk insert interface. This is not accessible to T-SQL; the best it can do (from SQL Server 2016 onwards) is to offer parallel bulk inserts on a heap table if you specify the `TABLOCKX` hint on the destination table, but I'm not sure this has any effect if you're reading data from a linked table. Writing *to* a linked table is hopeless, don't do that. Even SQL Server 2000 should be accessible with `OPENQUERY`, at least.

Comment: Note that the import/export wizard merely generates an SSIS package under the covers and runs it immediately; using an SSIS package yourself to transfer the data is an option. If SSIS isn't to your liking, any other client code that leverages `TRUNCATE TABLE`/`DROP/CREATE TABLE` with a bulk insert would do; in .NET this is offered by the `SqlBulkCopy` class. It depends a bit on your exact needs what is most convenient (if the table schemas are variable it's more challenging than if you're copying the same data repeatedly).

Comment: I've read about .NET SqlBulkCopy class, but it seems to me crazy to develop a tool in .NET to do that, just because the own SQL Sever does not offer a way to do it. But I will have a look to this solution as I don't see another one for the moment.

Comment: T-SQL has many things I'd consider crazy; not natively exposing the bulk insert interface isn't even in the top 10. But as someone with lots of experience under my belt in shoveling large amounts of data to and from SQL Server, trust me: custom tooling is the way to go if you need performance. Without any development, the best you could do is invoke `bcp` from the command line. Technically this *can* be done from T-SQL using SQL Server Agent and custom jobs, but doing this reliably is quite painful, and requires large files to be created at the server itself.

Comment: Yeah, i know the pain using bcp. Thanks for your comments @JeroenMostert

Comment: Bak and after restore

Comment: This way is not interesting for me but, just to let you know, it would not be possible. You cannot restore a backup from SQL2000 to SQL2012 directly. First you need to restore it on SQL2008R2 (other also possible) and then backup again, and finally restore it on SQL2012.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to simulate what import/export is doing, using Transact SQL commands?

Not quite.  But try running the INSERT from the other end.

```
INSERT INTO [DB1].[dbo].[Table3] SELECT * FROM [LinkedServer].[DB1].[dbo].[Table3]
```

Or install an instance of SQL Server 2008 and backup/restore to upgrade the database; then backup/restore that to the target version.

Comment: The problem here is that you propose to create the SQL2000 as a linked server on the SQL2012, and this is not possible as far as I could see. The opposite is possible, that's the reason i'm doing it in this sense.

Comment: You don't have to use linked server. Why not create some simple C# or whatever program that connects from SQL 2000 Server and fetches data from your SQL 2012

Comment: @Jortx If you're still using SQL 2000, you have a problem. It has been formally end of life for nearly **10 years** now. This means it has not received any updates... _not even critical security patches!_ It's dangerous and irresponsible to continue using it, and upgrading to something supported is job #1.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Believe me. But while this moment does not arrive, i need to do this data transfer in some way.

Comment: @siggemannen Yes, this is the only solution i'm finding for the moment, and if another does not apperar, i will do it like this.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 is also old as dirt, and still uses the old Windows OleDb driver for linked server by default.  It should connect to SQL Server 2000.

Comment: The error I got when trying to add the SQL2000 as a linked server on the SQL2012 was that SQLNCLI11 was not able to connect to SQL2000. With SQLNCLI10 is still possible to do it, but SQL2012 uses SQLNCLI11. Then I tried the opposite and it was possible because SQL2000 uses SQLOLEDB. This was my feeling.

Comment: You can create a linked server using SQLOLEDB on any version of SQL Server, eg `EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'whatever', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'SQLOLEDB', @datasrc=N'servername'` ...  As SQLOLEDB is a Windows component and it's still in the OS.

Comment: @DavidBrowne the linked server seems to be created using the command you propose (I can see it under Linked Servers list), but when I try to use it launching a simple query I get the message: `SQL Server Native Client 11.0 does not support connections to SQL Server 2000 or earlier versions`

Comment: Then I would use SSIS or backup/restore.

Answer (score 0):

I finally opted for @Jeroen Mostert's proposal, since no other working solutions have turned up.

I have created a small command line tool that receives the parameters for the source and destination connections. I've tested it with a table and it goes just as fast as the import/export does.

```
Using sourceConn As New SqlConnection(sourceConnStr)
    Using destinationConn As New SqlConnection(destinationConnStr)
        Dim cM As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " & sourceTable, sourceConn)
        sourceConn.Open()
        Using dR As SqlDataReader = cM.ExecuteReader
            Dim bC As New SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(destinationConn)
            destinationConn.Open()
            'Truncate
            cM = New SqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE " & destinationTable, destinationConn)
            cM.ExecuteNonQuery()
            'BulkCopy
            bC.DestinationTableName = destinationTable
            bC.WriteToServer(dR)
            'Close connections
            dR.Close()
            sourceConn.Close()
            destinationConn.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```